# how can i set the grub boot on a specific kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, kernel

i have a Dell PC after the grub was updated the Ubuntu boot entry generated a black screen which makes me choose a specific kernel in each boot operation .Any idea please ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1378212/edit) your question and add more details like your system specs, model or anything else that might help us help you.  Unfortunately, Dell PC could be any number of Dell models that are out there.  Add in if you added any addition video cards, etc.  What version of the kernel works for you?  Any more details would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood correct you question.
Please add to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved 
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

then run afterwards

```
sudo  update-grub
```

Boot up your desired kernel and for it will be set as default the following  boots.

For explanation please read

```
info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
```